# Python: Options for Freezing WITHOUT Dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-distribution

What options exist for shipping Python 3 code in a self-executing bytecode form but without the overhead of all dependencies (requiring Python to be installed on the user's computer)? I'm currently using PyInstaller to create all-in-one packages, but they're so large it would be useful to also offer a version that doesn't contain Python for those that already have it, which would presumably be orders of magnitude smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a docker container might help. Docker is an open source shipping platform. Make a docker image out of your code and ship the image. On the other side, you just need to run the image. Of course, you need to install Docker to pack and to run the image. you can find more details about docker [here](https://www.docker.com/why-docker).